# Excel formula to convert EST date time into IST date time?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to convert a EST date time column of excel into IST date time.

**For example:**

A1 column(EST) : 11/28/2015 11:38 PM

then I want the result to be in `IST (11/29/2015 10:08 AM)`

I tried some google search and got this below formula but its not giving result.

```
=IF(A1-TIME(10,30,0)<0,1+A1-TIME(10,30,0),A1-TIME(10,30,0))
```

Comment: India is more eastwards than US. So in India it is later than in US. So you must **add** time to EST to get IST, not subtract. `=A1+TIME(10,30,0)`

Comment: =IF(A1+TIME(10,30,0)<0,ABS(1+A1+TIME(10,30,0)),A1+TIME(10,30,0)) This above formula worked fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `=IF(A1-TIME(10,30,0)<0,ABS(1+A1-TIME(10,30,0)),A1-TIME(10,30,0))` works if your cell is properly formatted (the second last time formatting type)